# scikit-learn: how to scale back the 'y' predicted result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scale

I'm trying to learn `scikit-learn` and Machine Learning by using the Boston Housing Data Set.

```
# I splitted the initial dataset ('housing_X' and 'housing_y')
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(housing_X, housing_y, test_size=0.25, random_state=33)

# I scaled those two datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scalerX = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
scalery = StandardScaler().fit(y_train)
X_train = scalerX.transform(X_train)
y_train = scalery.transform(y_train)
X_test = scalerX.transform(X_test)
y_test = scalery.transform(y_test)

# I created the model
from sklearn import linear_model
clf_sgd = linear_model.SGDRegressor(loss='squared_loss', penalty=None, random_state=42) 
train_and_evaluate(clf_sgd,X_train,y_train)
```

Based on this new model `clf_sgd`, I am trying to predict the `y` based on the first instance of `X_train`.

```
X_new_scaled = X_train[0]
print (X_new_scaled)
y_new = clf_sgd.predict(X_new_scaled)
print (y_new)
```

However, the result is quite odd for me (`1.34032174`, instead of `20-30`, the range of the price of the houses)

```
[-0.32076092  0.35553428 -1.00966618 -0.28784917  0.87716097  1.28834383
  0.4759489  -0.83034371 -0.47659648 -0.81061061 -2.49222645  0.35062335
 -0.39859013]
[ 1.34032174]
```

I guess that this `1.34032174` value should be scaled back, but I am trying to figure out how to do it with no success. Any tip is welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think you need to apply scaling on your target variable. Scaling and other feature engineering techniques are applied only on the feature vectors.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use `inverse_transform` using your `scalery` object:

```
y_new_inverse = scalery.inverse_transform(y_new)
```

Comment: There's now also a meta-estimator which automatically takes care of this, see [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html)

Answer (score 15):

Bit late to the game: 
Just don't scale your y. With scaling y you actually loose your units. The regression or loss optimization is actually determined by the relative differences between the features. BTW for house prices (or any other monetary value) it is common practice to take the logarithm. Then you obviously need to do an numpy.exp() to get back to the actual dollars/euros/yens...

Comment: In some cases I believe you really do need to scale the y values as not doing so can result in various problems. One of them seems to be an increase in execution time in some cases. I experienced this with sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor, the execution time increased vastly after I moved away from scaling y. Then when I re-introduced scaling of y, the execution time was drastically reduced again. Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re

Comment: For general regression cases like houseprices I said not to scale them. Possibly I should have used the term 'transform' i.e. if there is no need then don't. E.g. going from dollars to K dollars is fine, but using e.g. the standard scaler is not needed in general. In any event, a prediction needs to be transformed back to the original unit...something lots of novices forget :-)