# Predicting values with Tensorflow neural network, after training it

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I've managed to train a neural network using Tensorflow. The following code does:

- Read an excel file (dataset)
- Scale data
- Build and run the neural network

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read file
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

# Make data a np.array
data = data.values

temp_data = []


for i in range(0, len(data)):
    date = data[i][0]
    time = data[i][1]
    temperature = data[i][2]
    dewPoint = data[i][3]
    dayOfWeek = data[i][4]
    apparentTemperature = data[i][5]
    kwh = data[i][6]

    temp_data.append([kwh, date.year, date.month, date.day, time, dewPoint, temperature, apparentTemperature, dayOfWeek])


data = temp_data

#split dataset
data_train, data_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)

# Scale data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler.fit(data_train)
data_train = scaler.transform(data_train)
data_test = scaler.transform(data_test)

# Build X and y
X_train = data_train[:, 1:]
y_train = data_train[:, 0]
X_test = data_test[:, 1:]
y_test = data_test[:, 0]

# Number of stocks in training data
n_time_dimensions = X_train.shape[1]

# Neurons
n_neurons_1 = 1024
n_neurons_2 = 512
n_neurons_3 = 256
n_neurons_4 = 128

# Session
net = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Placeholder
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_time_dimensions])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])

# Initializers
sigma = 1
weight_initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="fan_avg", distribution="uniform", scale=sigma)
bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()

# Hidden weights
W_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_time_dimensions, n_neurons_1]))
bias_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_1]))
W_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_1, n_neurons_2]))
bias_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_2]))
W_hidden_3 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_2, n_neurons_3]))
bias_hidden_3 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_3]))
W_hidden_4 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_3, n_neurons_4]))
bias_hidden_4 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_4]))

# Output weights
W_out = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_4, 1]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([1]))

# Hidden layer
hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W_hidden_1), bias_hidden_1))
hidden_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_1, W_hidden_2), bias_hidden_2))
hidden_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_2, W_hidden_3), bias_hidden_3))
hidden_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_3, W_hidden_4), bias_hidden_4))

# Output layer (transpose!)
out = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_4, W_out), bias_out))

# Cost function
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(out, Y))

# Optimizer
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(mse)

# Init
net.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Setup plot
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(y_test)
line2, = ax1.plot(y_test * 0.5)
plt.show()

# Fit neural net
batch_size = 256
mse_train = []
mse_test = []

# Run
epochs = 10
for e in range(epochs):

    # Shuffle training data
    shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(y_train)))
    X_train = X_train[shuffle_indices]
    y_train = y_train[shuffle_indices]

    # Minibatch training
    for i in range(0, len(y_train) // batch_size):
        start = i * batch_size
        batch_x = X_train[start:start + batch_size]
        batch_y = y_train[start:start + batch_size]
        # Run optimizer with batch
        net.run(opt, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})

        # Show progress
        if np.mod(i, 50) == 0:
            # MSE train and test
            mse_train.append(net.run(mse, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train}))
            mse_test.append(net.run(mse, feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: y_test}))
            print('Train Error: ' + str(round(100.0 * mse_train[-1], 2)) + ' %')
            print('Test Error: ' + str(round(100.0 * mse_test[-1], 2)) + ' %')
            # Prediction
            pred = net.run(out, feed_dict={X: X_test})
            line2.set_ydata(pred)
            plt.title('Epoch ' + str(e) + ', Batch ' + str(i))
            plt.pause(0.01)
```

So, now I read from another excel file to predict for new input X, using the following code:

```
#read file
data_predict = pd.read_excel("predict.xlsx")

# Make data a np.array
data_predict = data_predict.values

temp_data = []


for i in range(0, len(data_predict)):
    date = data_predict[i][0]
    time = data_predict[i][1]
    temperature = data_predict[i][2]
    dewPoint = data_predict[i][3]
    dayOfWeek = data_predict[i][4]
    apparentTemperature = data_predict[i][5]

    temp_data.append([date.year, date.month, date.day, time, dewPoint, temperature, apparentTemperature, dayOfWeek])

data_predict = temp_data
```

What I don't understand is how do I predict the new outputs Y for the given X.  I've come across many different code solutions, but none seemed to work for me: either because they can't, or I'm not familiar with the tensorflow syntax enough (I believe it's the latter).
*Note: I tried different variations of the tf.run() and tf.equal() methods, but I'm missing some of the required parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you should feed your test data to the trained network and the output of network will be your predicted labels.

You already did it in training process every 50 step, after "#Prediction" line, do it again for test data, like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(data_predict) // batch_size):
    start = i * batch_size
    batch_x = data_predict[start:start + batch_size] 
    pred = net.run(out, feed_dict={X: batch_x})
```

now the `pred` is a tensor with shape `[batch_size, 1]` include your predicted labels for test data.

Comment: Okay, so I scaled my new data, got my prediction. Is there a way to rescale it back to the original values?

Comment: Maybe `scaler.inverse_transform(input)`  can works in your case, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058774/scikit-learn-how-to-scale-back-the-y-predicted-result